# Error while Running POX controller script using Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, sdn, pox

I have written a POX controller script for my research and it is working great under `Python 2.7` interpreter (Using PyCharm IDE). However, when I choose `Python 3.5.1`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/XXX/pox/pox.py openflow.discovery my_controller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXX/pox/pox.py", line 42, in <module>
    import pox.boot
  File "/home/XXX/pox/pox/boot.py", line 55, in <module>
    import pox.core
  File "/home/XXX/pox/pox/core.py", line 155, in <module>
    import pox.lib.recoco as recoco
  File "/home/XXX/pox/pox/lib/recoco/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import recoco
ImportError: No module named 'recoco'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Has someone encountered such an error before?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with Python 3.X.

POX requires Python 2.7 according to the documentation [POX Readme](https://github.com/noxrepo/pox), [POX Wiki: Does POX support Python 3](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-DoesPOXsupportPython3%3F).

To run POX with Python 3, it would first be necessary porting POX to Python 3.

Use Python 2.7 and anything should work fine.